# Find out who truncate my mysql important table?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqlbinlog

My data in a Mysql table was cleaned by somebody, and I want to catch him.By analyzing  the binlog file I found this info:

```
# at 93029280
# 170904 13:30:54 server id 1  end_log_pos 93029379  Query    thread_id=26112 exec_time=0     error_code=0

 SET TIMESTAMP=1504503054/*!*/;
 TRUNCATE TABLE JTZRZ_FWDJ_DJJL
 /*!*/;
```

However I don't know what to do then. Can I get the executor ip address by the thread_id? Or anything else, help me please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You won't find it in the binlog (unless you have statements that use the username/host, or if you can conclude that from other statements). But you might have other log files on your system that may contain more information. E.g., if your database is connected to a website, you may want to look into your apache logs for things that happened around that time (e.g. sql injection attempts that may have resulted in a lot of error messages and one successful `truncate table`). Or you might find some connection information in either the mysql errorlog or, if enabled, the general query log.